# How to fix accordion transition Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I added some **CSS** in order to appear with a "+" sign in the side and transition when opened.

But now when someone opens the accordion the "+" transition is after the accordion is open and I want it to be at the same time.  Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong with the css?

Here is the link where you can see:  http://www.buhovisual.com/#servicios

Sorry attached is the code for the **CSS** transtion

```
.et_pb_accordion{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    width:78%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.et_pb_toggle {
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
    background: transparent;
    padding:6px 20px 25px;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:18px !important;
}    

.et_pb_toggle_open.animating .et_pb_toggle_title:before, .et_pb_toggle_title:before {

    height:1px;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    position: relative; left: auto; right: auto; float: left;
    content:"+";
    font-size:59px;
    font-family:'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
    width:30.666%;
    margin-right:3.5%;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }

.et_pb_toggle_close.animating .et_pb_toggle_title:before, .et_pb_toggle_open .et_pb_toggle_title:before {
    content: "+";
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: include some code...

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Questions should include the code if possible rather than a link to an external site that most people won't visit.

Comment: Sorry, I just added the code

Comment: Please include the HTML as well, or better still learn to use StackOverflow's code snippets, the <> button.